# Why can't I http response using jackson in spring mvc?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed a server program using spring mvc.
I need to use jackson for output data.
I added  in servlet-context.xml.
but, server response has error `http status 406`. The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
Why can't I http response using jackson in server?
And where is accept header in spring project using eclipse?

This is my servlet-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
  infrastructure -->

 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
  up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
  in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

  <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
   <beans:map>
    <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
   </beans:map>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari" />

 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jinggumdari" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="mysql1234" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
 <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
   <beans:list>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member</beans:value>
   </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
   <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="memberDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="memberService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.MemberManageServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="reviewDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.ReviewDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="reviewService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.ReviewManageServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="reviewDAO" ref="reviewDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

This is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.jbnu</groupId>
 <artifactId>jinggumdari</artifactId>
 <name>server</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
  <java-version>1.6</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.8.5</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
  <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- JDBC -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.30</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- javax.persistence -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- apache DBCP -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- JSON -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <additionalProjectnatures>
      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
     </additionalProjectnatures>
     <additionalBuildcommands>
      <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
     </additionalBuildcommands>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

This is my project explorer
[image]

Comment: Post your controller... First thing use Jackson 2 as Spring 4.x dropped support for jackson 1.

Comment: Also post your calling code.that's what sets the accept header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

in your pom.xml and use latest jackson